# Prevent user from accessing anything besides certain programs?

Tags: windows-7, restrictions

I need to create a user account that only allows a user to open one or two programs. Besides logging in and using those programs, he shouldn't be able to do anything.

I found two links on HowToGeek on how to restrict access to Programs and Hard drives, but this doesn't cover everything, does it?

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8035/how-to-restrict-access-to-drive-in-my-computer-on-windows/

Comment: What behavior specifically are you trying to prevent?

Comment: @Ramhound, block the user from doing anything else besides logging in and using 1 or 2 programs. I'm afraid just blocking access to programs and hard drives still leaves some vulnerabilities?

Comment: [AppLocker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831440.aspx) exists for this purpose